# How handle Invalid Session Id

Tags: c#, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to perform a re-login once my sessionId expires but for some reason the catch block is not being executed. The try block returns:

```
 "[{\"message\":\"Session expired or invalid\",\"errorCode\":\"INVALID_SESSION_ID\"}]"
```

I am now trying to access the property errorCode, but I cant seem to get it right. Please help.

```
    var requestResponse = (String)null;
      
    try
    {
         requestResponse = await apiCallResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    catch (FaultException fex)
    {
        if (fex.errorCode == "INVALID_SESSION_ID")
        {
           ...
        }
   }
```

Comment: Should be as easy as just calling the `<OriginalUrl>/services/oauth2/token` endpoint with your credentials. My gut feeling is you are using the returned `instance_url` again, and not the original entpoint ?

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do, but before I do that I need to check if the session is no longer valid

Comment: There are 2 approaches we use. Personally i just keep the last time we authenticated, and if the time (given a window is longer then x) just relogin. You should can and should also look at the response from calls, to make sure it hasn't expired, if it has, re authenticate.

Comment: My C# days are long gone but sounds like it's something else than FaultException? How does HTTP status 401 manifest in your code? Which SF API you're using and if REST - which OAuth2 flow? @TheGeneral's suggestion is so-so. Keeping time track is fine until SF admin decides to terminate your session in setup ;)

Comment: @eyescream  yeah we actually do a combination of both. preemptive, and reactive.